# How can I summarize a table considering the data flow in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Considering the following table:

```
|id | region| name  | date       |
|1  | 10    | JHONY | 2015-08-21 |
|2  | 10    | JHONY | 2015-08-21 |
|3  | 20    | JHONY | 2015-08-21 |
|4  | 10    | JHONY | 2015-08-21 |
|5  | 10    | JHONY | 2015-08-21 |
|6  | 10    | MARY  | 2015-08-21 |
|7  | 10    | MARY  | 2015-08-21 |
|8  | 20    | MARY  | 2015-08-21 |
|9  | 10    | MARY  | 2015-08-21 |
|10 | 10    | JHONY | 2015-08-21 |
|11 | 10    | JHONY | 2015-08-22 |
```

I need to summarize it, ignoring the duplicities of region, name and date, **but** when occurs a change of region in a same name at that date, it must consider one occurrence. In this case, would results:

```
| region| name  | date       |
| 10    | JHONY | 2015-08-21 |
| 20    | JHONY | 2015-08-21 |
| 10    | JHONY | 2015-08-21 |
| 10    | MARY  | 2015-08-21 |
| 20    | MARY  | 2015-08-21 |
| 10    | MARY  | 2015-08-21 |
| 10    | JHONY | 2015-08-22 |
```

I tried to use

```
select distinct region, name, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') from new_table;
```

as can be seen in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73c1f3/2

But it hides the rows #4 and #5 (which should result in a single row) and #9, which should be showed, due the change of region. Is it possible with MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the previous region.  I would approach this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.name, t.region, t.date
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.region
              from new_table t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.date = t.date and -- not sure if this condition is really necessary
                    t2.id < t.id
              order by t2.id desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_region
      from new_table t
     ) t
where prev_region is null or prev_region <> region;
```

For performance, I would recommend an index on `new_table(name, id, region)`.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73c1f3/3) is the SQL Fiddle.